# how do I set java version correctly in Gradle for Kotlin projects? (I can't access functions due to `No virtual method` error being received)

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

```
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    fun startStreaming(setImage: (ByteArray) -> Unit) {
        scope.launch {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // screenStream is an object of DataInputStream class
                    val jpegImageByteArray = screenStream!!.readAllBytes() //---error-here
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { setImage(jpegImageByteArray) }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000)
            }
        }
    }
```

## Error -

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.example.g_stream, PID: 19524
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method readAllBytes()[B in class Ljava/io/DataInputStream; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.io.DataInputStream' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)
    at com.example.g_stream.viewmodel.StreamViewModel$startStreaming$1.invokeSuspend(StreamViewModel.kt:119)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@a113203, Dispatchers.IO]
```

After some searches I concluded that the reason is because the code is being compiled to a lower java version. So, I tried fixing that but, it didn't change anything. here's the gradle script -

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.g_stream"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_12 //---see-here
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_12 //---see-here
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11' //---see-here
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
    namespace 'com.example.g_stream'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1' // do not update, keep 1.6.1
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------navigation
    def nav_version = "2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------espresso
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------barcode
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.0.3'

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------CameraX
    def camerax_version = "1.3.0-alpha02"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:$camerax_version"

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------joystick
    implementation 'io.github.controlwear:virtualjoystick:1.10.1'
}
```

Another post said this might be because this is a purely Kotlin project. So I tried setting the `jvmTarget` to 11. even that didn't help.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)` is probably the culprit here. The android device I was using didn't meet the spec. the `readAllBytes` function requires API 33. So naturally, since my device wasn't API level 33, the function wasn't found and hence, the error. And yes, my assumptions of this issue being a gradle problem was wrong.